# Intercepting HTTP requests

Tags: jquery, http, python-requests

I want to intercept HTTP GET, POST and AJAX requests on a page, redirect to my server, do somethings and then send the request to the original page. How should i do this? I tried using,

```
   $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        alert(settings.data);
        alert(settings.url);
    }
});
```

But is not working. Please let me know the Javascript/JQuery for this requirement.

Comment: You cannot intercept AJAX requests in this way, as this is the default options. Any setting in the request will override those in `$.ajaxSetup()`. I don't believe there's any way to detect an in-progress request and change its properties. It would be a security flaw if it was.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It would be a huge security issue if you could intercept and modify HTTP requests on a website. This is also known as [man in the middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and would offer huge possibilities to damage and abuse almost anything in the internet.